# How to investigate network buffers from a gRPC stream in go

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am looking to poke at the network buffers on a gRPC stream. I gather I need to access the `net.Conn` to do this but I am having difficulty finding out to access this. I have access to a `grpc.ServerStream`, have tried poking in the stream context and in other gRPC libraries but can't find a way to get it. Anyone have any advice here?

Comment: What do you mean "poke at the network buffers"?  What are you trying to do, exactly?  Note that gRPC streams are not 1:1 with `net.Conns`, as many streams may be in flight on one `net.Conn` at any point in time.

Comment: @DougFawley I want to track that state of the network buffers to see if they are getting full on the server side, due to slow clients or clients not reading. If the network buffer is full for a period of time I would like to disconnect the client

Comment: follow up: In bash terms I believe running `ss` and looking at the `skmem`, particularly `wmem_queued` would be what I'm looking for

Comment: Well, you could try to use TCP level information, which you could probably do by creating your own `net.Listener` (wrapper) which you pass to `grpc.Serve`, and then monitoring those connections.

EDIT: (Pressed enter by mistake.)  I'm not sure why you want to do this, though.  HTTP/2 level flow control will make the server stall those connections if the clients aren't reading off their streams.  This is potentially an anti-pattern that leads to compounded problems if you kill the connection.

Comment: thanks @DougFawley i'll look into it. a gRPC stream can stay alive for a very long time, HTTP/2 wont kill it. Coalescing can only do so much to built up notification, eventually the application heap memory will grow excessively and their will be pressure put on the producers. Once channels start filling up deadlocking will occur.

Comment: What you said at the start is true, but there is H2 flow control that will stop the producer from doing too much unnecessary work and to stop memory from growing excessively as well on the producer side.  Any deadlocks after that would be a problem with your application (e.g. both client and server are trying to write to the same stream but neither is reading).

Comment: Another thing you may want to check out is max connection age: https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A9-server-side-conn-mgt.md#proposal